# Horizontal menu - gap in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, menu

I'm working on a small personal website that is 940px wide. I wanted to build a menu with 6 elements that is full width of the website. I have managed to make the menu perfect in Firefox, Chrome and Opera, but in IE I've got a little (4-5px) gap at the end of the last element. Any ideas how can I remove that space?

Here is CSS for the menu:

```
#menu ul {
     list-style: none;
     width: 100%;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-right: 1px solid #C1BEBA;
    padding: 10px 56px 10px 56px;
}
```

and HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tmn3Q/)**

Comment: HTML line 3: Change `<li><a href="#"">Menu 2</a></li>` with `<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>`, `"#""` is error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code and your plan.

1. You really need to decide: do you want any space between the menu items. 
   If you don't, and you want them touching each other, and touching the sides of the 940px wide page, then your current plan won't work, since 940/6=156.666 recurring. This is not pixel perfect and will look bad.
   If you want space between the menu items, then you need to set a width for all your menu items. If you just use padding, the moment you put in too much or too little text, the page layout will break, or will be uneven unless you use more CSS.
2. Your code has errors is some places, like #menu ul. It should be ul#menu. This is why some of your code wasn't working.
3. You need to use a CSS Reset for IE if you want it to look the same as in your other browsers. I've used a simple reset in my code below, but I suggest you Google IE CSS Resets and choose the most appropriate one for you.
4. Here is sample code that I've put together. I've changed quite a bit of yours, but hopefully it will help. I've added a right margin for li tags, and then a negative margin for the a tags to make sure the text centers nicely between the borders. This would change if you wanted the menu items to have a different background color, and you'd just need to do the math with your CSS widths and margins.

You can see the full example of this code at:
http://code.bengrunfeld.com/iewithhorizontalmenu.html

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
    background:#aaa;
    width:940px;
}

ul#menu {
    background:#fff;
    list-style: none;
    width:940px;
    height:80px;    
}

#menu li {
    width:145px;
    display:inline-block;       
    padding: 30px 0;
    margin-right:13px;
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px solid #C1BEBA;
}

#last {
    margin-right:0px !important;
    border-right:none !important;
}

#menu a {
    width:158px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:-13px;  
    display:block;
}

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li id="last"><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
</ul>
```